# Opencart product specials discounts "Options" bug or feature

Tags: opencart

As the opencart has a Special option tab that allows a promotion to be added, I'm trying to do the following:

have a product with a price of 100$
have a second version of the product via the Options tab that is 50$
and a 3rd version of the product that is 150$

and run a special price. The idea is to be able to select a special price for any of the options, but at the moment it's not working at all. If I set a special price to 21$ the product page displays only the 2 options of 50$ and 150$ removing the default of 100 (which is ok - i can add a 3rd for the default) but has no effect on the options prices. Is there an extension or a fix that can allow me to achieve that - the discount from the special offers tab to affect the price from the options tab. It's my first time working with opencart so it's all a bit new to me.

Here's a link to a test product:
http://www.hqperfumery.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=67&product_id=1727

you can see that it strikes out the price and offers the new price but it's the same though the amount discounted from the standard price is correctly calculated under the product name

Thanks for any help provided

Comment: It's not a bug, it's your mistake somewhere - you didn't setup special/discount feature and options properly. Since you're new in OpenCart, I'd recommend you to play with it for a while and read documentation.

Comment: well, there are not lots of options there to setup - you add a price for the discount, and an option with a price and that's it - there are dates and such that can be either added or not, but does not affect the functionality. Is there any other configuration settings for those that i'm missing

Comment: Just looked briefly in your code and noted, that price is recalculated on radio button change by recalculateprice() function. This is NOT standard OC function, so you should seek support of the developer of extension, which added recalculateprice() function to your store.

Comment: ah, thank you. Checking from where that came and if it can be removed

Comment: *but does not affect the functionality* - sure it does - if you add dates (valid from and valid to) you can limit when the special or the discount is available (e.g. from some date, to some date or between the two). Also do not mix up the special and discounts in OC as their purpose is completely different, special set's the *sale price* while the latter one sets discounted prices depending on the amount of units ordered. Also each other setting has it's effect on the functionality.

Comment: yeah, but that has nothing to do with the problem i have - e.g. with the special price on the options of each product